# jqGrid - clicking on row removes altclass and hoverrows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, hover, zebra-striping

We use jqGrid with `altclass` set and with `hoverrows:true`.  When you click on a row, the `altclass` class is no longer applied and the hover effect no longer works on the clicked row.   How can you stop this from happening?

Comment: Not sure I quite get the question, but how can you have the 'altclass' and the 'clicked' class applied at the same time?

Comment: Oh so jqGrid applies a `clicked` class when you click on a row?  That would explain the behavior.  Any way to have jqGrid NOT apply the `clicked` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add custom code to the `onSelectRow` event to prevent the row from being highlighted when clicked. For example:

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    jQuery(myGrid).resetSelection();
}
```